# Randomly redirect to url BUT 1 number changes (via Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, random

So, I use this code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "/truth";
urls[1] = "/truth1";
urls[2] = "truth2";

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

and I use "/truth1" "/truth2" "dare1" etc

Is it at all possible to have javascript automatically put a random number at the end of the URL between what I set it to?

In other words
I want Javascript to add a number to the end of
truthordare0.weebly.com**/truth**
truthordare0.weebly.com**/dare**
To truthordare0.weebly.com**/dare1**, truthordare0.weebly.com**/dare2**
To truthordare0.weebly.com**/truth1**, truthordare0.weebly.com**/truth2**

putting a random number between 1-25 at the end of "truth" or "dare". If I have to make the numbers two-digit, please let me know!

**It might be handy to know:**
-The code above will be used on truthordare0.weebly.com**/truth**
(which will redirect to **/truth1**, **/truth2**, etc
-The code above is used in vitemulti.weebly.com/yesorno-select

Thank you very much!!

Comment: what's your question? It is not clear what you want

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "/truth";
urls[1] = "/truth1";
urls[2] = "truth2";

var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = "https://truthordare0.weebly.com/" + urls[random];

</script>
```